# How do you pass an object into a setinterval?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, game-engine

for example, say I use a factory to create a group of objects:

```
function factory() {
    e.x = 0;
    e.y = 0;
    return e;
}
```

How do I pass these objects into a render function?

For example:

```
function render() {
    a[0].someMethod;
}

function init() {
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        things[i] = factory();
    }
    setInterval(render(things),40);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use closure there:

```
setInterval(function(){
   render(things);
},40);
```

`setInterval` accepts *callback* function (function with name without `()`) but when you do:

```
setInterval(render(things), 40);
```

You are actually *calling the function (because of `(things)` parenthesis) right there* inside `setInterval` which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() { render(things) },40);
```